# List & Map Marker clicks

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-play-services

I've got an `Activity` that holds a `ListFragment` on the left and a [`SupportMapFragment`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment.html) on the right.

List and Map are both backed by the same data. The visual representation of the data on the Map are [`Markers`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker.html).

I want to be able to perform a click on **either** a list item **or** a Marker and get the corresponding item in the **other visual representation**.

**Restrictions of the framework and my data are:**

1. The Marker class is final and the Marker's id does not have a modificator. This is why I can't use the easiest possible way.
2. > "It's important to not hold on to objects (e.g. Marker) beyond the
   >   view's life. Otherwise it will cause a memory leak as the view cannot
   >   be released." (see [SupportMapFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment.html))
3. Titles of Markers can occur multiple times. This is why the expensive String comparison is not a way I can go.

Does anyone have a working solution for this issue or can provide a nudge in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to be able to register to clicks on a Marker, you'll need to override the [`InfoWindowAdapter`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter).

You can provide unique information to the title and snippet of a Marker and implement the interface's methods in this style:

```
@Override
public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
  // do nothing here in order to obtain the original info window border.
  return null;
}

@Override
public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
  // Create your own view here. Obtain the unique information stored
  //  in title / snippet of the current marker.
  return createdView;
}
```

Now you can set the [`OnInfoWindowClickListener`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener) and work with the unique information stored there.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option. The latest APIs provide an [OnMarkerClickListener](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener) interface.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker#marker_click_events